# Shortcut to command in terminal

Tags: fedora

I currently have a command in linux terminal that I run a lot which is

```
pyclewn ==window=none .....
```

My question is if there is a way for me to assign a shortcut to this command
I am using Fedora 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can use alias

Like :

```
alias alias_name='command you want to run'
```

Eg :

```
alias ll='ls -la'
```

You have to put this into the file `.bashrc`

In order to have it working you will need to run the following command :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Cheers.

Comment: could you tell me where .bashrc is located ?